# Add object to child object array in another object contained in state within an NgRx reducer

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, reduce, ngrx-store

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to add a new object to an array contained withing a piece of state. That array is part of another object as part of my state.

In my situation I have Deck object that contains an object array, Card[]. You can see this in my state object currentDeck.

I have found any attempt to manipulate currentDeck outside the reducer results in the error *"can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length".* Which has led me to realize I need to be doing this properly in the reducer after some research.

I have a NgRx effect that dispatches a success action, *addCardCurrentDeckSuccess*, that adds a new card to the deck. This requires not just changing the Cards array but probably the deck I assume. The action I have dispatched passing in a card the needs to be added to the currentDeck objects Card[].

I have an addCard method in the Deck object which I assume will be required in the solution.

My code and data structures are below. I've removed most of the irrelevant variables and other reducer actions.

At the moment I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require installing the 'immer' module. I've done some reading normalizing my dataset but I'm not sure how I can do that here either.

Any help would be appreciated.

My State and Reducer

```
export interface MyState {
  decks: [],
  currentDeck : Deck;
}

export const initialState: MyState = {
  currentDeck: undefined,
}

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(saveCurrentDeckActions.saveCurrentDeckSuccess, (state, { currentDeck }) => ({
    ...state,
    currentDeck
  })),
  on(addDeckActions.addDeckSuccess, (state, { deck }) => ({
    ...state,
    decks: [...state.decks, deck]
  })),
  on(addCardToCurrentDeckActions.addCardCurrentDeckSuccess, (state, { card }) => ({
    /* Can't seem to nail down the syntax here
          currentDeck.AddCard(card) */
  }))
);

export const MyFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'MyFeatureSelectors',
  reducer
})


// Deck
import {Card} from "./card.model"

export class Deck {

    deckId    : string = "";
    name      : string = "";
    cards     : Card[] = [];
    

    constructor() {
        this.deckId     = "";
        this.name       = "";
        this.cards      = [];
    }

    public addCards(cards: Card[]) {
        this.cards.push.apply(this.cards, cards);
    }

    public getCards() : Card[] {
        return this.cards;
    }

    public addCard(card : Card) {
        this.cards.push(card);
    }
}

//Card
export class Card {
    name: string
    id: string

    constructor(json? : any) {
        this.name          = json?.name;
        this.id            = json?.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `Array.push` because it mutates the array and therefore the state, which is breaking one of the fundamental rules of ngrx - state should be immutable.

You need to perform all such state changes via the reducer in an immutable way.

Also don't store `currentDeck` as a `Deck` as that is duplicating the same state that exists in the `deck` array which violates the single source of truth principle - use an index instead.

```
export interface MyState {
  decks: Deck[],
  currentDeckIndex : number;
}

...

on(addCardToCurrentDeckActions.addCardCurrentDeckSuccess, (state, { card }) => {
   // add the card to a a copy of the relevant deck
  const updatedDeck = [...state.decks[currentDeckIndex], card];
  
  // replace decks with an array that has the updated deck inserted
  return {
    ... state,
    decks: state.decks.map((deck, index) => index === currentDeckIndex ? updatedDeck : deck)  
  }; 
})
```